# win32 GUI display text from char array variable in window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface

I wish to display the characters from a character array onto a window using win32. The second parameter type is wrong. How can i solve this? Thanks

```
char data[5]="hello";

CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT(data), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | 
                WS_BORDER|ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
                 10, 50,300,300,hWnd, (HMENU) none, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const TCHAR* data = TEXT("hello");    // LPCTSTR 

CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), data, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | 
            WS_BORDER|ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
             10, 50,300,300,hWnd, (HMENU) none, NULL, NULL);
```

Your code is not compiled in Unicode configuration. Using generic TCHAR type should solve the problem.

Another way, if data is `char*`, using ATL conversion macros (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx):

```
#include <atlstr.h>

const char* data = "hello";

CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), CA2T(data), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | 
            WS_BORDER|ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
             10, 50,300,300,hWnd, (HMENU) none, NULL, NULL);
```

And finally, for completeness, you can call ANSI API version explicitly:

```
const char* data = "hello";

CreateWindowA("STATIC", data, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | 
            WS_BORDER|ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
             10, 50,300,300,hWnd, (HMENU) none, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: thanks! it worked out well. That second parameter value is LPCTSTR right? What if my the data must be in character array form? Is there any workaround to this? Or must I convert from char array to char pointer?

Comment: You can use ATL conversion macros. For example, if data has `const char*` type, you can convert it to `const TCHAR*` by this way: `CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), CA2T(data), ...` Include `atlstr.h` for this.